SwiftUI access @Environment from enum
I have an enum that handles the theme for my app. I would like to have a .system option where it will return a different value depending on the system's theme (light or dark). Below is how I have it implemented, irrelevant code removed:
enum Theme: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case system
    case dark
    case light
    /* more cases */

    var mainColor: Color {
        @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
        
        switch self {
            case .system: return colorScheme == .dark ? .dark : .light
            default: return Color(rawValue)
        }
    }
}

When I run it, though, I get the error Accessing Environment<ColorScheme>'s value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update. This makes sense, as obviously the enum is not a view. With that said, how can I access the colorScheme environment variable from my enum? Or is there a different way to do this?

This is not possible. Accessing a @Environment value is only possible inside of a SwiftUI View.
But since mainColor is just a computed property not an enum case, you could replace this computed property with a method and call this method instead:
enum Theme: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case system
    case dark
    case light

    func mainColor(colorScheme: ColorScheme) -> Color {
        switch self {
            case .system: return colorScheme == .dark ? .dark : .light
            default: return Color(rawValue)
        }
    }
}


Then you can add @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme to your view and pass colorScheme as an argument:
Theme.system.mainColor(colorScheme: colorScheme)

